# Notify RecyclerViewAdapter from MainActivity

Tags: sqldataadapter, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

In my `MainActivity`, I handle my methods for database changes and also the listen for an icon clicks in the toolbar.
The icon performs that the list from database (shown in Recycler View) gets ordered ascending/descending.

But the Problem is when i click the icon the list only gets updated after i reopen the Fragment.

My thoughts : how can i open a method from the Adapter? Or update the RecyclerView in the `MainActivity` in some way? Thanks for sharing ideas

**Edit :**
supposedly i found a similar scenario :) so i have to try to implement an Listener from the Fragment where the RecyclerView Adapter gets shown ( listen to Main activity) and from there call Adapter.notifiyDataMoved() ?

Comment: create public method in adapter, then call that method like adapter.someMethod(); then do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Solved it with an public method in adapter updateList(list<object> list) which deliveres the New list from my database and then inside the Methode notifyDataSetChanged() . but thanks :)